# Any difference declaring class using :: or module?

Tags: ruby

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ABC
    end
  end
end


class Api::V1::ABC
end
```

Any different between these to declare a class?

Any pros and cons?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those two are equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference while you will be doing [*constant lookups*](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=ruby+constant+lookup&source=bl&ots=fIJovd6rjH&sig=DX9uladCMOHEVcGr6nrP8Ir1_Nw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q5BaU-KKKImyrgf31YDABQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=ruby%20constant%20lookup&f=false). [`Module::nesting`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting) will be helpful here to things get cleared for you.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ABC
      p Module.nesting
    end
  end
end

# >> [Api::V1::ABC, Api::V1, Api]

module Api
  module V1
  end
end


class Api::V1::ABC
  p Module.nesting
end
# >> [Api::V1::ABC]
```

`Module.nesting` returns the lexically enclosing classes/modules which are searched before Ruby walks up the **class/module** hierarchy to find the constant.

It means, with the following code :

```
module Api
  module V1
    X = 12
  end
end

X = 10
class Api::V1::ABC
  p X
end
Api::V1::ABC.superclass # => Object
# >> 10
```

While constant *looks-up* will be happening, it will first search to the array of constants, which has been given by `Module.nesting`, if not found then, up to the ancestor chains/included modules. It means following to the `Api::V1::ABC.ancestors` outputs.

Now in the above example, you can see that value of `X` printed, which is defined in the `Object`, not inside the `API::V1`. The reason as I said above.

Now coming to another example below :-

```
X = 10
module Api
  module V1
    X = 12
    class ABC
      p X
    end
  end
end

# >> 12
```

Here the constant look up will follow through the array `[Api::V1::ABC, Api::V1, Api]`. You can see the output found as `12`, as `Api::V1` has a constant `X` defined into it.

Thus we can say - **Yes there is a difference between the 2 declarations**.

Comment: Also, in the second case, if the "parent" modules were not already defined, an `NameError: uninitialized constant` exception is thrown upon declaration of the class.

Comment: @HolgerJust That's obvious.

Comment: Yes, but it is the most common reason to avoid the second variant in actual code (which normally uses constants rather sparsely).

Comment: Humm.. But if every things are present, then still there is a difference that I tried to explain.. :)

Comment: Sure. That's why I upvoted your answer :) You give very valid reasons why the first variant is generally better suited. I just wanted to add an additional reason...